Help me to combine two hypotheses in a multiple linear regression model for ANOVA comparison!
I am currently studying multiple linear regression and practicing with stock market data. My dataset includes:

Dependent variable (Y): S&P 500 price

Independent variables:

Gold price (X1)

Copper price (X2)

Best performance sector (X3): A categorical variable encoded as follows:

XLK (technology) or XLE (energy) = 1

All other sectors = 0


I have two hypotheses that I would like to test:

Copper price (X2) interacts with XLK/XLE (X3=1), but not with other sectors (X3=0).
Gold price (X1) does not interact with any best-performing sector (X3).

I want to combine these two hypotheses into a single model and create a reduced model to compare with the full model using anova(full_model, reduced_model) in R. However, I’m unsure how to construct the reduced model in such a way that it reflects both hypotheses.
full_model <- lm(SP500_Adj_Close ~ Gold_Price + Copper_Price + 
                  Performing_Sector_Dummy +  
                  Gold_Price:Performing_Sector_Dummy + 
                  Copper_Price:Performing_Sector_Dummy)

The above is my full model. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
Could you please help me construct the reduced model and guide me on how to test these hypotheses appropriately?

Setting aside that some people would suggest doing a time-series regression for stock prices, I can see that you're simply trying to understand how multiple regression works (and that you've only got cross-sectional data).
Let's unpack a bit.
With your full model specification you'll have the following regression coefficients (in addition to an intercept):
$\beta_{\text{Gold price}}$: change in S&P Index as gold price increases by 1 unit in the "all other sectors" group
$\beta_{\text{Copper price}}$: change in S&P Index as copper price increases by 1 unit in the "all other sectors" group
$\beta_{\text{Sector}}$: difference in mean S&P Index between the two sectors
$\beta_{\text{Int 1}}$: difference in the linear relationship between gold price and S&P Index when the sector changes to tech or energy
$\beta_{\text{Int 2}}$: difference in the linear relationship between copper price and S&P Index when the sector changes to tech or energy
Each coefficient has a $p$-value from a $t$-test of the default $H_{0}: \beta_{p} = 0$. Thus, both hypotheses are tested within your full model.
If you would like to test the joint hypothesis:
$$
H_{\text{joint null}}: \beta_{\text{Int 1}} = \beta_{\text{Int 2}} = 0
$$
Then remove the interactions from you model so that it is just:
SP500_Adj_Close ~ Gold_Price + Copper_Price + Performing_Sector_Dummy

Fit that new reduced model (which is nested in the more complex model), and the F-test will give you a p-value for the joint test.
So no need to even do the model comparison if you're interested in testing the two interaction hypotheses separately.
